# Split Camel Context definition into multiple files/jars

Tags: apache-camel

I need to split the camel context definition into multiple files/projects. I'd like to have one file with only global configurations (like dataFormats, onCompletion handler, onException handler, interceptFrom, operational routes) and one file which builds on top of it defining mainly routes.

I have not found any way to adjust/extend a CamelContext definition done in another file. Is there a way?

It would look like this:

camel-core.xml:

```
<camelContext id="camelContext">
    <interceptFrom>
        <log message="{$routeId} started" />
    </interceptFrom>
</camelContext>
```

camel-routes.xml:

```
<camelContext id="camelContext">
    <route id="camelRoute1">
        <from uri="vm:foo" />
        <log message="camelRoute1 completed" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Desired output when running camelRoute1:

```
camelRoute1 started
camelRoute1 completed
```

Comment: This is currently not supported.

Comment: Pity! Thank you for the response

Comment: @ClausIbsen Is this going to be supported any time soon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a workaround with the Java DSL for my case:

1. In the camelContext definition i set autoStart="false"
2. In my project where the global camel definitions should be, I added a spring bean which implements both [ApplicationListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) and [CamelContextAware](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContextAware.html)
3. In this bean I get all the route definitions from the camel context - including the ones defined in another project/context file. So I loop through all route definitions and add interceptFrom, onException etc. with the Camel [adviceWith](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html) feature.
4. I then start all routes with context.startAllRoutes().

works :-)

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to do this.
Use `<import resource="myCoolRoutes.xml"/>`

See documentation - http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-import-routes-from-other-xml-files.html

Comment: Thanks! but this feature is not powerful enough for my example. I cannot extend routes and definitions like interceptFrom and onException are not applied by the routeContext